# Do Android/iOS devices support these codecs/containers?

Tags: android, ios, streaming, h.264, aac

I have searched high and low, and nowhere can I find if newer Android/iOS devices ship with media players that can stream media (with the following characteristics) *from inside an app*:

- Streaming MPEG-TS over UDP/IP
- Video using h.264 codec
- Audio using AAC codec

Is this even possible? If not, why (is the container incompatible, or some other reason)? If so, how (what software/media player do they need)? If it is possible, I need a way to open that media player from inside the app, but have no idea how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Capture your TS and try to play it through the respective Mediaplayers -- the apps aren't terribly difficult to mock up. When you know that it understands your codecs, and the TS container, you can go build a UDP socket to feed the Mediaplayer.

Comment: Thanks @323go (+1) - a few followups: (1) Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say "*capture* your TS..."? Do you mean save the entire stream off to a file, or use a temp file that the stream is constantly writing to, and that the media player is constantly reading from? (2) Also, what do you mean by "build a UDP socket"? Do you mean doing that from inside my app? Or something else? Thanks again!

Comment: (1) Yes, you can capture part of your TS for testing purposes. I used to do that with an HDHomeRun before mythTV had support for it, and the resulting captures would play fine in VLC. If you can play such a capture using the Android or iOS Mediaplayer components, then you know the container and codecs are supported.
(2) If you know your containers are supported, but the players don't receive streams, then you can build your own UDP receiver, buffer, etc and feed the players directly. At least on Android, they receive IOStreams.

Comment: I know it's not trivial -- but it should get you there.

Comment: Ok thanks again (+1), this is *starting* to make sense. So let's say that the Android/iOS mediaplayer components can play a captured TS, but don't receive the actual streams. Are there even networking APIs/libs/frameworks out there for Android/iOS that would allow me to build a UDP receiver/buffer/etc.? I'm kind of looking for a proof of concept here. Thanks again for all the help so far.

Comment: Android is Java, so all of the Java universe is available. You probably want MulticastSocket or UDPInputStream. Additionally, there's a ton of OSS out there, much in a commercial-friendly license. I haven't dug as deep with iOS, but afaik all the socket communication should be accessible from objectiveC, since it's just a superset of C++ anyway.